# Setting up different passwords for Filevault 2 and my user account

Tags: macos, filevault, carbon-copy-cloner

I'm currently setting up Carbon Copy Cloner to create a backup clone of my SSD. I'd like to be able to store the cloned drive's Filevault 2 password in the keychain so CCC can access it to automatically do backups on a schedule. However, I don't want to store my administrator password in the keychain. (I've heard of a few exploits that allowed malware to access stored passwords).

Is there a way to set up a separate Filevault password for the cloned drive?

I'm running a MacBook 8,1 with El Capitain 10.11.6.

Comment: Are you talking about the FV password of the source drive (the one in your Mac) or of the backup drive?

Comment: The FV password for the backup drive.

Comment: A drive password is different from a login password, so Right know I don‘t fully understand your problem. Can you elaborate a bit more on where the admin password comes into play here  and how it seems that they must be the same?

Comment: To backup what @patrix stated, the FileVault 2 password is for the encrypted drive. It is encrypted on boot up. This FileVault password is stored in the keychain which is the accessed when you login with your user, since the user's password unlocks the keychain the FileVault password is in.

Comment: @patrix According to [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204837), the way it works is: "When FileVault setup is complete, your Mac restarts and asks you to log in with your *account* password. Your password unlocks your disk and allows your Mac to finish starting up." Bombich also recommends you clone to an unencrypted disk, then boot into it and enable FileVault. When you enable it, there is no option to set a separate disk password. In fact, all new user accounts' passwords will also decrypt the disk.

Comment: @Janhein Are you saying that when you turn on FileVault, it creates a separate password for the disk, then doesn't tell you about it and automatically stores it in the keychain? I've looked at my keychain and there does not seem to be an entry for a FileVault password. Or a disk password for my internal SSD.

Comment: The quote refers to the encryption of the boot drive, not of an external drive. Unlocking the boot drive works different (obviously IMO as storing the boot drive key in the keychain is kind of pointless)

Comment: The clone is a bootable drive. [Bombich recommends](https://bombich.com/kb/ccc5/working-filevault-encryption) doing the initial clone to an unencrypted external drive and then booting into it and turning on FileVault as you would on the internal drive. That sets the drive password to my admin password just as enabling FileVault on the internal drive does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't have CCC be able to unlock a drive without storing those credentials somewhere.  The best you could do is create a new account that has the ability to unlock the drive and store those credentials instead, which unlocks the drive but not your primary administrator account.

Comment: This worked, but there was one hiccup. Since I had set up FileVault on the external drive before I had created the second user on the internal drive, I had to manually enable the second users account in FileVault on the external drive. It was automatically enabled on the boot drive, but that setting was not carried over via cloning. I also made that second user "Managed" under parental controls and revoke every privilege I could. So, as much as possible, it functions *solely* as a password for the disk.

Comment: I also found some [instructions](https://blog.filippo.io/filevault-2-custom-passphrase/) to set up a separate password without creating a second user. It makes booting from the external drive slightly more complicated as my admin password would no longer unlock the drive at all. Also, while I did not try it, `diskutil coreStorage changeVolumePassphrase` may also be an option.

Comment: But doesn't this login the user after filevault? I don't want the user to login. Just to unlock the disk. Seems Apple is helping NSA a bit too much here. Why force people to use a frequently used password to be the same as the one for filevault.

Comment: @mjs yes it does. What does this have to do with the NSA? I think there's a way to give a non-administrative user FileVault unlock privileges, that might address your concerns as it would unlock the disk but only log you into an empty user profile. Then you can log out and into the one you really want, with a separate password.

Comment: I am already at that point. I just don't want to be logged in and out. I prefer if I was able to get to the login screen and choose later how to log in. Very obtrusive, especially if you have several disks to be unlocked. There are issues with this approach. I am just saying that by default they've connected the filevault password to the user password which we enter daily hundreds of times. Prior they used to allow a disk password that was separate, or even, change the user password so that the login would fail. Now, they longer allow a disk password, just a user connected one.

Comment: @mjs write a script to log you out and run that on login, then.

Comment: @Harv you are describing hacks. In Mojave, I was able to change the password of the user, but retain the filevault password so the login would essentially fail. Seems they have now stopped that loophole. I was also able to actually use a disk password as well so I did not even need to do this at all. Seems all these tricks are there to confuse people. Would not be surprised if Apple has their own institutional filevault key as well at this point. Regardless I am ok now, I can log out as I don't restart computer that often anyway.